# Write an integer or boolean value in text files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function contained in a class:

```
def new_config(self):
    dict_dat = {"Display Set": self.main.id[20], "Display Width": self.main.id[4], "Display Height": self.main.id[5],
                "Fullscreen": self.main.id[9], "Music Volume": self.main.id[11], "Sound Volume": self.main.id[13],
                "Voice Volume": self.main.id[15], "Ambient Volume": self.main.id[17], "Other Volume": self.main.id[19]}
    cgo = open(self.path, "w")
    for name, dat in dict_dat.items():
        cgo.write(name + ":" + dat)
    cgo.close()
```

In the various "self.main.id" contains Integer and Boolean values. I would like to know how I can write in a text file, line by line, the value name (example "Display Set") and the value (self.main.id [20]), without having to convert everything into a string.

As I wrote above, I get the error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` The fact, however, is that if possible, I would like to write data without having to convert it.

With another file I used the Pickle module, but reading the file by opening it manually, it is unreadable for any person, so it makes it useless in this case.

Comment: But you *do* want to convert it to a string... otherwise it won't be human readable.

Comment: So I must obligatorially convert to string? Because the only idea that came to me was to save a dictionary and load the dictionary then when the file was read. But in that case I had to put the brackets in the file.

Comment: If pickle is useless why are you trying to use it? BTW the error message is unrelated to writing data, it is about you trying to add a number to a string..

Comment: Sorry, I realized later that, by copying the test I had done previously, there was still a pickle. Now I have corrected again.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 As I said you cannot add a number to a string.

Comment: I unfortunately understood my stupid mistake. I had not thought the mistake could be this sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

A smart solution for you would be to use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), available in Python 3.6+, as follows:

```
def new_config(self):
    dict_dat = {"Display Set": self.main.id[20], "Display Width": self.main.id[4], "Display Height": self.main.id[5], "Fullscreen": self.main.id[9], "Music Volume": self.main.id[11], "Sound Volume": self.main.id[13], "Voice Volume": self.main.id[15], "Ambient Volume": self.main.id[17], "Other Volume": self.main.id[19]}
    with open(self.path, 'a+') as f:
        for name, dat in dict_dat.items():
            f.write(f'{name}:{dat}\n')
```

If `dat` is a boolean True or False, it writes "True" or "False".
If `dat` is an integer, it writes the integer value.

*Note 1: I also strongly recommend you to use `with ... as ...` statement, which automatically and properly closes the file at the end of the block.*
*Note 2: Unfortunately I have finally learnt that you were using Python 3.4. So this solution is not relevant for you (you get a syntax error on f-string). You can either upgrade to 3.6+ or replace the f-string with `'{0}:{1}\n'.format(name, dat)`.*

Comment: Excuse me very much, I edited the following script for a mistake that I had not noticed.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 I have updated my answer. For me it answers your request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I think there is a syntax error, since trying your solution, I get the error.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 Could you please detail which error do you get ?

Comment: `file.write(f'{name}:{dat}\n')
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: The arrow was on the apostrophe

Comment: Which Python version are you using ? Because f-strings are available only in Python 3.6+...

Comment: Python 3.4, since some modules I use are not yet updated to higher versions than that.

Comment: However, I thank you very much for your help, especially for your advice

Answer (score 2):

As I said before, you can just `print` to a file.

```
def new_config(self):
    dict_dat = {
        'Display Set': 20, 
        'Display Width': 4, 
        'Display Height': 5,
        'Fullscreen': 9,
        'Music Volume': 11,
        'Sound Volume': 13,
        'Voice Volume': 15, 
        'Ambient Volume': 17, 
        'Other Volume': 19,
    }
    with open(self.path, 'w') as cgo:
        for name, idx in dict_dat.items():
            print(name, self.main.id[idx], sep=':', file=cgo)
```

Comment: Excuse me very much, I edited the following script for a mistake that I had not noticed.

Comment: It's no problem at all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the `string.format` method:

```
file.write('{0}:{1}\n'.format(name, dat))
```

[image]

Comment: `file.write("{0}:{1}\n".format(name, dat))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Comment: Also, in this way the "dat" is saved as a string?

Comment: not writeable sounds like you have a lock on the file

Comment: see screenshot of output.

Comment: Excuse me very much, I edited the following script for a mistake that I had not noticed.

Comment: why not just wrap your arguments in the `str` function?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using JSON:

```
import json

# write your dict
with open(self.path, "w") as file:
    json.dump(dict_dat, file)

# read it back
with open(self.path) as file:
    loaded_dict = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Excuse me very much, I edited the following script for a mistake that I had not noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Per **write()** method of Open() built-in function. 
Please check the documentation. - *f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written. To write something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first.*

https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

You can change your code in this way.

```
file.write(str(name) + ":" + str(dat) + "\n")
```

Comment: Excuse me very much, I edited the following script for a mistake that I had not noticed.